# In ggplot2, is it possible to create a bar chart with buckets that contain overlapping data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am making a bar chart where data is being bucketed by some continuous variable X.  I would like to create a bar chart where the buckets actually overlap.  So if the binwidth=1/10, then the first bar would contain data with Xs in the 0th to 10th percentile.  The second bar might contain data with Xs from the 1st to 11th percentile.  The third would contain data with Xs from 2nd to 12th percentile.  And so on.  Is something like this possible in ggplot?

Edit:

I should clarify.  I don't want the bars to overlap *visually*, so I've removed your edit Martin.  Instead I would like adjacent buckets to partially share data points.  It's important to note that

1) My X data has been percentiled already.
2) The bars are reporting a summary statistic of the bucketed data, such as variance.

So, in a normal bar chart with a binwidth of 1/10, you'd have the 1st bar represent the data in the 0-10th percentile, the 2nd bar represent 10-20th percentile, and so on.  However, what I want is for the 1st bar to represent the 0-10th percentile, the 2nd bar to represent the 1-11th percentile, the 3rd to represent the 2-12th percentile, and so on.  The reason for doing so is just to decouple the binwidth from the number of bars shown on the graph.  I want a wide bucket, but I'd like to view those buckets at very small intervals to see a more continuous bar plot.

Comment: What is the purpose of such a chart? I'm asking because even though I don't know of a way to make bars overlap, there might be a type of graph that could suit your purpose.

Comment: The reason for doing so is just to decouple the binwidth from the number of bars shown on the graph. I want a wide bucket, but I'd like to view those buckets at very small intervals to see a more continuous bar plot.  Basically its just to smooth out the visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better you bucket your own data first, then plot as required. It will give you more flexibility. Agree with @BrodieG that `rollapply()` is easiest e.g.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(zoo)

p_data<-data.frame(n=0:99,p=runif(100)*10)
window<-10

buckets<-data.frame(label=rollapply(p_data$n,10,function(x)paste(x[1],x[window],sep="-")))
buckets$avg<-rollapply(p_data$p,window,mean)  # mean
buckets$tot<-rollapply(p_data$p,window,sum)   # total
buckets$var<-rollapply(p_data$p,window,var)   # variance
buckets$custom<-rollapply(p_data$p,window,function(x)x[1]+x[2]+5)   # anything you like

qplot(buckets$label,buckets$avg,geom="line",group=1) +     # plot mean
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible with ggplot. Try this `ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.5))`

Now for the explanation

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
```

The first command in the code block, is default dodging (side by side bars).
The second command you're telling ggplot how much to "dodge" by, with the width parameter.
Play with width till you get what you want.

Read this http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/position_dodge.html for more details on position_dodge.
Also, for your question on binning, you can supply your own breaks, read this http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_bin.html

Comment: I don't believe this addresses my question but I might be wrong.  I further clarified my question with an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Taken to the limit, what you are doing is plotting a kernel density function.  Here I create a vector of 200 random normal observations, and plot the rolling density using `stat_density`:

```
vec <- rnorm(200)
qplot() + stat_density(aes(x=vec))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's good to know.  Could I display a summary statistic that is more complex than count?  If I had vec2 <- rnorm(200) and I wanted to see the average variance of vec2 for each bucket, is there a way to do this?  It seems like it's just for estimating the distribution of a single variable.

Comment: I don't know if it can be done directly, but you can do easily use `zoo::rollapply` to run a function through a rolling window of the values in a vector.  So in this case you would plot the result of `rollapply(vec, width=10, var)` which will calculate the variance for all sets of 10 contiguous points in `vec`.